# oracle: sql union query

Tags: sql, oracle

i have a database that has the following tables

```
EMPLOYEE:[FIRST_NAME, MID_INIT, LAST_NAME, SSNO, BDATE, ADDRESS, GENDER, SALARY, SUPSSNO, DNO]
DEPARTMENT:[DEPT_NAME, DEPT_NO, MGRSSNO, MGR_START_DATE]

DEPARTMENT.MGRSSNO is a foreign key of EMPLOYEE.SSNO
```

I need to build a query using a UNION to display the names of all employees, and if they are a dept manager, the dept_name.

Here is what i have

```
SELECT E.FIRST_NAME, E.LAST_NAME, E.ADDRESS, D.DEPT_NAME
FROM EMPLOYEE E, DEPARTMENT D
WHERE E.SSNO=D.MGRSSNO
UNION
SELECT E.FIRST_NAME, E.LAST_NAME, E.ADDRESS, D.DEPT_NAME
FROM EMPLOYEE E, DEPARTMENT D;
```

except i am getting 36 rows (9 employees x 4 departments) instead of the 9 that I should be getting.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Your second subquery has no join condition, so it produces a full cross-product of the two tables.

Comment: You should be using a `LEFT JOIN`, not `UNION`.

Comment: You should be using explicit `JOIN`s instead of the old-style implicit join conditions in the `WHERE` clause

Answer (score 0):

Use a `LEFT JOIN`, not `UNION`:

```
SELECT e.FIRST_NAME, e.LAST_NAME, e.ADDRESS, d.DEPT_NAME
FROM EMPLOYEE e
LEFT JOIN DEPARTMENT d ON e.SSNO = d.MGRSSNO
```

Comment: I have to use a UNION.

Comment: If it's homework, I'm not going to do it for you. You need to replace the second subquery in your union with one that only returns the employees who aren't department managers.